# Python & OpenCV : Find Unknown People

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, face-recognition

I have a code that recognizes some people faces which are in my dataset and it uses opencv. It works perfectly when a person who is in my dataset come to front of webcam and it shows his name perfectly.

But when another person who is not in my dataset, it shows same name too. It should show "Unknown". Here it is my code;

```
import sys
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime

import cv2
from skimage.filters import threshold_mean

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def Draw_Text(img, sTxt, aX=30, aY=30):
    if ""==sTxt: return
    cv2.putText(image, str(sTxt) ,(aX,aY), font, 
        fntSize,(0,255,255), fntThickness,cv2.LINE_AA)


def CvBGR_To_RGB(img):
    return cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)


def Load_LabelIDs(fn):
    labelNames = []
    with open(fn) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            lines = str(data[i]).split("\\n")
            for s in lines:
              labelNames.append(s)
    return labelNames

labelNames = Load_LabelIDs('labelIDs.txt')
labelDics = {}
for s in labelNames:
    strs = str(s).split("=")
    labelDics[strs[0]] = strs[1].split("\n")[0]

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
fntSize = 1
fntThickness = 1

fnClassfier = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(fnClassfier)

fname = "trainner.yml"
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read(fname)

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    return_value,image = camera.read()  
    imgInfo = np.asarray(image).shape     
    if len(imgInfo)<2: break
    imgH=imgInfo[0]
    imgW=imgInfo[1]
    imgChannel=imgInfo[2] 

    gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
         cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
         Id,conf = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
         #print (conf)
         key = "{}".format(Id)
         if (key in labelDics):  
             Id = labelDics[key]
         else:
             Id="Unknown"
         newimg = cv2.putText(image, str(Id), (x+2,y+h-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (150,255,0),2)


    try:                 
        Draw_Text(image, "esc:exit")
        cv2.imshow('image',image)

        key = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if key == 27:  #esc   ord('s'):
            #cv2.imwrite('test.jpg',image)
            break

    except ValueError:
        break

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried to edit

```
if (key in labelDics):  
        Id = labelDics[key]
    else:
        Id="Unknown"
```

But after many tries, I couldn't find. Can you help me?

EDIT:

My labelIDs.txt file contains only this line `1=wicaledon`. So If I add `print(key, Id, labelDics)` it shows always `1 1 {'1': 'wicaledon'}` even known or unknown person see the camera.

Comment: use print to display values in variables - `print(key, Id, labelDics)`. You could also use `print( key in labelDics )` . Maybe this help to find problem.

Comment: instead of `"{}".format(Id)` you can do `str(Id)`. If `Id` is already a string then there is no need to use `str()` or `"{}".format(Id)`

Comment: I tried your print line and it shows `1 1 {'1': 'wicaledon'}` even known or unknown person see the camera @furas

Comment: as for me problem in `recognizer`. What value it should return for unknow person ?

Comment: I checked some tutorial for `LBPHFaceRecognizer_create` and I think it has no option to not recognize person. it will always try to recognize person and it will always give some ID for existing person - it will be ID of more similar face (even if it will be ony 0.000000001% similarity). If you will have only trained on only one person then every face will be similar to this one person.

Comment: in this tutorial it use images with uknown faces so later prediction can use this information to give ID of unknown face. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/24/opencv-face-recognition/

Comment: @furas this tutorial has some differences so we need to find the problem in this code I think

Comment: as for me problem can be dataset. Did you use some random images with label "unknow" ? If there is no "unknown" label then it can't give ID for "unknow". It will it will give ID of the most similar face even if similarity will be small  0.000000001%. As for me model has no option to return ID for "unknown" if it didn't learn it.